# Issue with input lookup screen on flow

Tags: lightning, visual-workflow

I have a detail page button (content source - url) from where a VF Page is called which in turn calls a Flow. Now , I want to insert a screen with lookup , so I started with the standard lookup component . When I tested the same I got the error that *it isn't supported in Classic runtime* , so I created a custom aura component , placed it on the flow just to test if it works but still I get the same error message while testing.

Is this happening because of the flow getting called from Visual Force page? What would be the ideal workaround for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replaced the custom button with a quick action and called the flow from the same (used standard lookup on a input screen ) and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

The Lookup component is built using Lightning technology and requires the Flow Lightning Runtime to be activated.

Activate the Flow Lightning Runtime via Process Automation Settings in Setup. It will change the looks of your existing Flows, but generally for the better.

Comment: Lightning Runtime is already enabled and the error still shows up.